# SQL query to select childs and parent

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I have a mysql table 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy' with 2 fields.

*tid* -- Primary Key: The taxonomy_term_data.tid of the term.
*parent* -- Primary Key: The taxonomy_term_data.tid of the term’s parent. 0 indicates no parent.

I need to get 1 level children terms for some term, but if it have not children, than get children for it parent. Something like:

```
SELECT down.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy down WHERE down.parent=60
IF ( COUNT(down.tid) = 0 ) THEN
   SELECT current.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy current 
   WHERE current.parent=
        (SELECT its.parent FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy its
         WHERE its.tid=60)
```

Can I do it at single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible with one query because you need an `IF` statement to determine which query to use.  You can, however, create a stored procedure to handle the logic for you, and call it by passing the `tid` into it.  Here is the stored procedure I created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getChildren(in _tid int)
BEGIN

  DECLARE hasChildren BIT;

  SET hasChildren = EXISTS (
    SELECT ''
    FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy tth
    WHERE tth.parent = _tid
  );

  IF hasChildren THEN
    BEGIN
      SELECT tid, parent
      FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy
      WHERE parent = _tid;
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SELECT tth3.tid, tth3.parent
      FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy tth1
        INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy tth2 ON tth1.parent = tth2.tid
        INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy tth3 ON tth2.tid = tth3.parent
      WHERE tth1.tid = _tid;
    END;
  END IF;

END//
```

I created the schema on [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cce9a/1) so you can test it out for yourself.

Comment: Great! It's helps a lot.